# How to change a characters image in 'touchbegan' in spritekit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm currently using Sprite Kit and Xcode to design a game. My character is usually in the state of running which consists of two images - code below:

```
bobSKTexture* Texture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"bob1"];
bobTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKTexture* bobTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"bob2"];
bobTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

SKAction* run = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[birdTexture1, birdTexture2] timePerFrame:0.2]];

_bob = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:birdTexture1];
[_bob setScale:2.0];
_bob.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 4, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[_bob runAction:run];
```

I want the image to change when a touch to the screen happens, only for a short amount of time and then I want it to return to the above code. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I have changed my answer slightly. Does it fix your problem now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jānis K said, it would be even easier to do like this when you want the image to change:

```
[_bob removeAllActions];
_bob.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:NEW_TEXTURE];
[self performSelector:@selector(resetAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f];
```

`NEW_TEXTURE` is the name of the texture/image you want it to change to.

`self` would be the scene or wherever you call the code to make `_bob`

This is the `resetAnimation` method, defined in your scene or wherever you call the code to make `_bob`:

```
- (void)resetAnimation
    {
        SKAction* run = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[birdTexture1, birdTexture2] timePerFrame:0.2]];
        [_bob runAction:run];
    }
```

Comment: would I add the nastier in the void reset animation

Comment: Where would I add the NSTimer and how?

Comment: When changing the texture (_bob.texture = ...), you can do e.g. "[_bob performSelector:@selector(resetAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f]", to reset the animation after 2 seconds.